# Why Apache server start automatically everyday and it stops the nodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, ssl-certificate, mean-stack

I am working in MEAN STACK application, I face one issue in a live site.
In my live web site, I have stop Apache server and run nodeJs by using pm2.
Once nodeJs started by pm2, my site running very well, but after every next day, Apache server automatically starts and my nodeJs site stop.
After stopping of Apache server the nodeJS works fine.

> app.js

```
"use strict";
var logger = require("./config/log");
var express = require("express");
var https = require('https');
var http = require("http");
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var config, hostName, sslOptions, httpServer, callSocketDir;
/**
* @description all process variables
*/
require("./config/vars")(app, fs);

config = require("./config/config.js")(app, express);
callSocketDir = './socket';

sslOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(global.hzConfig.privateKey),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(global.hzConfig.certificate),
    passphrase: global.hzConfig.passPhrase
};
httpServer = https.createServer(sslOptions, app).listen(global.hzConfig.port,function (req, res) {
    logger.log("info", 'my site is listening on ssl port ' + global.hzConfig.port + ", proccess id is " + process.pid + '!');
    initEmailServer();
});

require(callSocketDir)(app, httpServer);
```

> Stop apache server

```
/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl stop
```

> Start nodejs server

```
pm2 start httpsServer.js
```

> dependencies

```
"express"  => "version" : "4.13.4",  
"nodeJs"   => "version" : "v7.4.0",  
"https"    => "version" : "^1.0.0"
```

Please give me a proper guideline for this issue.
[image]

Comment: this seems a certification error , not a server start/stop error.

Comment: Thanks, but if it seems certification error then how after stops Apache Server and start the nodejs is working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the Apache server and nodejs server might be on the same port 
for example 
if node js server running on port 80 and your Apache server to port is also running port 80

try and set one of the server to port 8080